# What is the better way to retrieve value from this cache implementaion?

Tags: java, cache

I have the following methods in `CacheUtil` class

```
public void addCacheEntry(String key, Serializable entry) {
    //add to cache
}

public void removeCacheEntry(String key) {
   //remove from cache
}

public Serializable getCacheEntry(String key) {
   Serializable entry = // get from cache
   return entry;
}
```

And in the class where I use the cache, I have the following methods,

```
public List<String> fetchList() {
   List<String> aList = (List<String>) CacheUtil.getInstance().getCacheEntry("aList"); //IDE warns of unchecked casting
   if(aList == null) {
     aList = fetchFromDB():
     CacheUtil.getInstance().addCacheEntry("aList", new ArrayList<String>(aList));
   }
}
```

How could I have avoided the warning of unchecked cast? I can not change the methods in cache to store lists explicitly, as I want to store anything that is serializable in cache and that is just a library.

I believe there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your CacheUtil class to the following:

```
public class CacheUtil {
    ...
    public void addCacheEntry(String key, Serializable entry) {
        //add to cache
    }

    public void removeCacheEntry(String key) {
       //remove from cache
    }

    public <T extends Serializable> T getCacheEntry(String key) {
       T entry = // get from cache (probably needs a cast to T)
       return entry;
    }
}
```

which would allow you to get cached entries by type T without a cast:

```
    public List<String> fetchList() {
       ArrayList<String> aList = CacheUtil.getInstance().getCacheEntry("aList");
       if(aList == null) {
         aList = fetchFromDB():
         CacheUtil.getInstance().addCacheEntry("aList", new ArrayList<String>(aList));
       }
    }
```

Notice that I was required to use ArrayList, because List is not Serializable on its own.  You could take this one step farther and have getCacheEntry() return T without extends:

```
    public <T> T getCacheEntry(String key) {
       T entry = // get from cache (may need a cast)
       return entry;
    }
```

But Im not sure I'd take that leap.

Comment: Hi @johncari, thanks for the suggestion. Changing the method signature in CacheUtil to <T extends Serializable>, moves the unchecked cast warning to CacheUtil class (when casting entry to T). Is there anyway i can avoid that too? That warning is not bad?

Comment: You could add this to the method to avoid the warning: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Comment: @SenthilKumar By moving the cast elsewhere and adding SuppressWarnings you wan't improve it. There are two problems: 1. You need `class CacheUtil<T extends Serializable>` so you can create type-safe caches (look at `List` or any such collection). 2. And then you can't use `CacheUtil.getInstance()`, which is a good thing as such a static method prevents you from using multiple caches.